# How to store links between variables in a datatype's field?

Tags: julia

Say I have a type that's designed to store information including links to other variables:

```
type MyList
    a::Int64
    b::Int64
    connections::Array
    MyList(a, b) = new(a, b, [])
end
```

This `link` function would put the name of the second variable into the `connections` list in the first (if I knew how to do it):

```
function link(x_1::MyList, x_2::MyList)
    push!(x_1.connections, #= name of =# x_2)     # <------------- ?
end
```

Then I'd be able to do this:

```
a1 = MyList(11, 22)
a2 = MyList(33, 44)
a3 = MyList(55, 66)
a4 = MyList(77, 88)    
link(a1, a2)
link(a1, a3)
link(a1, a4)
```

and then I could check the connections with:

```
a1.connections

-> [a2, a3, a4]
```

and do things like this:

```
for conn in a1.connections
    println(conn.a)
end

-> 
33
55
77
```

That is, if I could work out how to store the names of the variables in the `connections` array in the first place.

Or perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: why not link by using `Ref`s?

Comment: Just a thought: the terminology is really bad here. The words `link` / `connections` are misleading to me; they seem to imply a _bidirectional_ link, whereas what you're doing here is a _directed_ link. Furthermore, your use of the term `list` is also misleading, since what you're building seems to be a tree, not a "linked list". I'd use terms like "MyTree", "NextNode" / "Children" instead.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes, my Minimal Working Example was a bit over-simplified, if not actually brain-dead, but it was hopefully conveying the essence of what I was trying to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why cannot you just add the second list to the connections? If I understood right what you want, it'll do the thing.

Notice that this way you are not getting a copy of x2 in x1.connections, you are getting there just a pointer to x2.

Look:

```
julia> function link(x1::MyList, x2::MyList)
           push!(x1.connections, x2)
       end

julia> a1 = MyList(11, 22)

julia> a2 = MyList(33, 44)

julia> a3 = MyList(55, 66)

julia> link(a1, a2)

julia> link(a1, a3)

julia> for conn in a1.connections
           println(conn.a)
       end
33
55

julia> a2.a=333
333

julia> a3.a=555
555

julia> for conn in a1.connections
           println(conn.a)
       end
333
555
```

Comment: Thanks. I was convinced that it stored the all the data (which might be larger). I'll have to take a closer look...

Comment: @daycaster if this answer satisfies your question (which I believe it does), please accept it so that the question can be 'closed' off properly.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou OK. But I was wondering whether Julia's metaprogramming could do something clever. But this answer works.